# preg_replace: Regular expression not work

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
<h1>title 1</h1 w:id="0"/><p>content</p><h1>title 2</h1 w:id="1"/>...
```

I want to replace `w:id="0"/` from `</h1 w:id:="0 or 1 ect "/>`

I use this code:

```
preg_replace("</h1 (.*?)>",'',$html)
```

But it doesn't work anymore

Comment: You probably need additional [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: Just add a little: What do you get now, What do you expect and all your tries!

Comment: yes it code not work

Comment: Yes, code not work. We know. And it's going to stay that way unless you concretize.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`regular expressions`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) on PHP Manual?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the delimiters on your regex.

A regex needs a 'starting mark' and a similar 'finishing mark', so PHP can interpret it's content as the match, with all it's flags.
Without the recognized delimiters, it's impossible to diferenciate between simple text and a regex.

Try this regex:

```
@</h1 (.*?)>@
```

Or:

```
~</h1 (.*?)>~
```

PHP supports a few more delimiters, like `<>` and `/`.

---

As a side note, I would suggest the following regex:

```
~</h1( [^>]+)?>~i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_replace("/<\/h1 (.*?)>/i",'</h1>',$html);
```